# Postal board games out there besides chess

Tags: chess

I am interested in board games which can be play through a period of time, e.g. one turn per day. The most typical is chess, there are a few websites including www.chess.com. Then recently I been playing at arimaa.com which is a game similar to chess and has a postal option.

Does anybody knows of any other board game which can be play online and have the same functionality?

Comment: You can try Diplomacy, it is often played by (e)mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other strategy board games also have things like this. If you like Chess, you might also enjoy Go. Here is a link to an online website where you can play correspondence Go:

https://online-go.com/

In general, what you are looking for are correspondence games, so here is a website with a bunch of these games:

http://gamesbyemail.com/

Answer (score 1):

People play Diplomacy in that manner.  It give you lots of times to contact other people to make deals with them between submitting your moves.

Comment: That sounds like how real diplomacy worked before the invention of telecommunications.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://game.asup.co.uk/login.php) links to an online automated port of [Supremacy](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/27/supremacy) with long turn timers (upwards of 72 hours to my knowledge, all player's turns occur simultaneously).